# Internet Explorer 8 freezes on debug with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I have an ASP.NET web application that I've been working on for the past few months. Recently I've encountered a problem where when I start debugging and internet explorer launches it locks up. I've tried waiting, but it hangs indefinitely. This happens about 75% of the time. I know it will lock up if the progress bar doesn't show up in the footer. If the progress bar appears then everything works fine. It's turned into a ritual of starting/stopping debugging until it works. If I use Firefox everything works fine. However I can't avoid IE forever as this application is being used in a closed environment where all users are using IE8 exclusively.

I know it's not code related as everything was fine on a Friday, and then with no changes made, it started behaving this way on Monday. I've also opened other web applications and they suffer from the same problem.

I've made sure everything is up to date in Windows Update. I've looked for any updates/fixes to Visual Studio 2010. I haven't been able to find any posts anywhere describing this problem. There's nothing in my logs showing up either.

I'm running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit with VS2010 SP1.

Edit: I've also tried running the solution with IIS instead of the built in dev server, but it had no effect.